# How to use text file variables in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, azure-devops, scripting

I have a variable text file, in which All of my variables are there. I wrote a script through which I get the content of the file, here's the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
value=`cat dev.txt`
echo "$value"
```

And I got this output on my terminal screen.

```
location = "centralus"
location_abr = "cus"
client_name = "fair"
client_name_prefix = "f"
resource_group_postfix = "rg"
project_name = "OTOZ"
environment_name = "devtest"
instance = "04"
Clusterabr= "aks"
```

But, I want to use the value of the variables which I got in the output. For example, I want to get the value of `Clusterabr`, But I cannot get it.

Comment: You'll have to **parse** `dev.txt`, so it all depends on its format; can you explain it extensively? Can there be comments in it? how does a value with `"` in it is escaped? Are all values double-quoted? Are there always one space around `=`? Can the keys contain spaces? How is a newline escaped? etc...

Comment: @Fravadona,Yes The format of that file is exact that I've shown you.

Comment: You didn't tell how you are running your script. In the way you post it, it is more likely that it is a `sh` script and not  a `bash` script.  As for your config file: You have to write a parser for this. If you can trust the configfile (no dangerous statements inside), and you can be sure that the configuration values don't have embedded spaces, a simple/stupid parser would be to just remove all spaces from the file (use `tr` for this) and then simply _source_ the config file. This would turn configuration variables into shell variables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
value=`cat dev.txt`
# echo "$value"
#get the value of Clusterabr in dev.txt
value1=`cat dev.txt | grep Clusterabr | cut -d "=" -f2`
echo $value1
#remove "" from the value
value2=`echo $value1 | sed 's/"//g'`
echo $value2
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: How can we concate now??

Comment: As when I do concate 2 or multiple strings, I got spaces between them, Here's the code in next comment

Comment: client_name=$(cat "$file" |grep client_name_prefix| cut -d "=" -f2 | tr -d '"')
                  env_name=$(cat "$file" |grep environment_name| cut -d "=" -f2  | tr -d '"')


AKS_NAME="${client_name}${env_name}"

echo $AKS_NAME


I got this output:   f  devtest
The expected output is :    fdevtest

Comment: @Muhammad_Bilal Seems the issue comes from the format of your file, if the standard format this issue will not occur: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmvW8.png. And in your situation: file="./dev.txt"
client_name=$(cat "$file" |grep client_name_prefix| cut -d "=" -f2 | tr -d '"')

env_name=$(cat "$file" |grep environment_name| cut -d "=" -f2 | tr -d '"')
#remove blank space from env_name
env_name=$(echo $env_name | tr -d ' ')
echo $client_name
echo $env_name

#AKS_NAME equals to the value of client_name + env_name
AKS_NAME=$client_name$env_name
echo $AKS_NAME

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A ary                  # associative array to store name-value pairs
pat='^([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*"([^"]+)"$'
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $pat ]]; then
        ary[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    fi
done < dev.txt

echo "${ary[Clusterabr]}"       # example
```

Output:

```
aks
```

- The regex `$pat` matches the line assiging `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` to the
  lvalue and `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}` to the rvalue.
- `ary[$name]="$value"` assigns an associative array `ary` indexed
  by "$name" to "$value".

Comment: +1 for the regex solution, but `printf -v "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` feels a little dangerous, I would build an associative array instead.

Comment: @Fravadona you are absolutely right! I've updated my script accordingly. Thank you for the suggestion! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have an even better solution, based on the `source` command, as you can see:

```
Prompt>source dev.txt
Prompt>echo $location
Prompt>centralus
```

I must admit that you might need to do a small modification in your code, removing the spaces around the `=` characters, like:

```
Prompt>cat dev.txt
location="centralus"
location_abr="cus"
...
```

As you might have guessed, the `source` command treats your `dev.txt` file as a piece of script source code.

Comment: Since dev.txt as have spaces around the assignment, instead of requesting them to be removed, you can do something like `$(tr -d ' ' <dev.txt)` (I didn't test this. If it does not work, you can alternatively send the output of `tr` to a temp file and source that temp file).

Comment: @user1934428: you are right. However I have no idea where the mentioned `dev.txt` is coming from. There might be two solutions: either change the file after it has been created (your proposal) or modify the way this file gets created. Let's leave that decision to the author.

Answer (score 0):

With the given data/input. With the assumption that there is only one `=` in each line. With `bash` and `sed`.

```
source <(sed 's/[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*/=/' file.txt)
```